# Regular expression which will support forward slashes and fullstops

Tags: c++, regex

I need to find a regular expression which will support the following format

```
.[A-Z-a-z]/-
```

Would `^(\.[A-Za-z]\/-?)+$` work fine ?

**i.e**

```
.V/-.E/-
```

**BUT THE `-` IS OPTIONAL**

I trield `^(\.[A-Za-z]\/-)$`
but i cannot seem to find a regular expression to support the `-` at the end

Could someone show me where i am going wrong please.
Thanks

Comment: Which regex library are you using? PCRE? re2?

Comment: what specifically are you trying to capture? the entire string?

Comment: Did you try the regex you've mentioned?

Comment: I have tried it now it works and i am using Boost::Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the regex to match the string `".V/-.E/-"`, you could use this:

```
^(\.[A-Za-z]\/\-?)+$
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `-` ?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to, but I don't know what regex library the OP is using, and regex libraries often vary. I just escaped it to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as adding a `?` after the `-`. The whole regex would be `^\.[A-Za-z]\/-?$` (don't need the parens unless you are using backreferences)